# web3js returns non-checksumed addresses!

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, addresses, checksum

Why does web3js 0.20.6 returns all-lowercase addresses on contract creation not a checksumed address?!

How to deal with this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
web3.utils.toChecksumAddress
```

EDIT:
Sorry, just saw you mean 0.20.6, so its:

```
web3.toChecksumAddress()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that was not supported in web3 0.x , try to implement the function by yourself

found this code hier [eip-55](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-55)

```
const createKeccakHash = require('keccak')

function toChecksumAddress (address) {
  address = address.toLowerCase().replace('0x', '')
  var hash = createKeccakHash('keccak256').update(address).digest('hex')
  var ret = '0x'

  for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(hash[i], 16) >= 8) {
      ret += address[i].toUpperCase()
    } else {
      ret += address[i]
    }
  }

  return ret
}
```